# IE deletes cookies that should not be deleted

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I have a problem with IE8 and IE9.
I login to a certain web site (site A), then on the other tab login to another site(site B). And when I logout from site A, IE deletes it's cookies (and this is right) and login cookies from site B, so that I have to login to site B again.

I need to resolve situation with site B. Because I cannot change site A.

This problem happens not for every site B, but only for a few ones, e.g. Gmail. For the others it works just fine. And Firefox doesn't have such problem either. Sorry, unfortunately I cannot give A site URL and login/password because it isn't in public availability.

Can anyone have any idea what it is?

I would be very grateful for any piece of advice.

PS. I've just found out that when I logout from site A, IE deletes all cookies with "EXPIRES" field equals "At the end of the Session", not just from it own domain, but from all other domains too.

Does anybody know why IE behaves so?

Comment: If both site A and site B are provided by the same service group (so to say) like Google provides Gmail, Gtalk, Google Search etc which share the account, then logging out of one will log you out of the other (at least for most of Google's services)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not the answer. Site A and B are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the name of the cookie if the cookie name for both the website is same like for site A and site B .then it will delete it. or both site has same domain may be the issue.

If site is from same domain then it will delete the whole domain cookie.